# how to call inherited class constructor in the inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

I need to call inherited class constructor  in the inner class. Say i have Outerclass that inherits Baseclass and i have an inner class inside Outerclass. From this inner class's constructor i need to invoke BaseClass constructor?

```
public class BaseClass {
    public BaseClass (WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver =driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, maxTimeOutForElement), this);    
    }
}

public class OuterClass extends BaseClass {
    OuterClass (WebDriver driver)
    {
        super(driver)
    }

    //Does something

    public class InnerClass
    {
         InnerClass (WebDriver driver)
         {
             //is there a way  to call Baseclass constructor super(driver) 
             //I don't want to call directly new AuthorLoginPage(driver) breaking
             //my constructor chain.
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: The serious answer is: don't do this. So you don't need to know. But I disagree with the downvotes. This is a valid question, although I regard the *practical* usefulness of this: very close to 0.

Comment: @Michael this is not a doubly nested class. If you look this has only one level of innerclass.

Comment: @Michael I have formatted the code again. This is not doubly nested class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to:

```
//is there a way  to call Baseclass constructor super(driver)
```

is **no**. Keep in mind: `InnerClass` isn't **static**. This means: objects of `InnerClass` can't exist "on their own". The only way to create an instance of `InnerClass` is by **first** creating an instance of `OuterClass`.

At the point in time when `InnerClass` objects can be created (their constructor code being executed) - there is no point in calling the constructor of the super class. Because `InnerClass` has no superclass (besides Object). And it doesn't make sense to call the constructor of the enclosing `OuterClass` - because that `OuterClass` object already exists!

Or, explanation via code:

```
OuterClass outer = new OuterClass(someDriver);
OuterClass.InnerClass inner = outer.new InnerClass(someDriver);
```

Leading to: step back, and look into your model. It doesn't make much sense on a first deeper glance.

And to address the comment by the OP: `InnerClass` **extends** Object! It has *no* **direct** relation to `BaseClass`. Besides the fact that any `InnerClass` object belongs to an `OuterClass` object - and that one extends `BaseClass`!

Comment: So *maybe* what he wants is to make `InnerClass` static and also extend `BaseClass`? But that raises the question of why `InnerClass` wouldn't just exist as a class on its own.

Comment: @Michael It is no coincidence that I did *not* talk about that part ;-) To the contrary, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you both, I specifically need this structure to construct page objects in selenium . @Michael yes i could have them as class on its own. The only thought i had was to model my page structure  where there are several divs.

Comment: @GhostCat doesn't the innerclass has super class via the outer class  ?

Comment: @GhostCat I think you mean to say OuterClass.InnerClass inner = outer.new InnerClass(someDriver);

Comment: @deepakguna It says so. Just have a look. No, thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Extend InnerClass from BaseClass and you will good. Here is a slightly modified version of your code :

```
    public static class BaseClass {
        public BaseClass (String driver)
        {
            System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + driver);
        }

        public class OuterClass extends BaseClass {
            OuterClass (String driver)
            {
                super(driver);
            }
            //Does something

            public class InnerClass extends BaseClass
            {
                InnerClass (String driver)
                {
                    super(driver);
                    //is there a way  to call Baseclass constructor super(driver)
                    //I don't want to call directly new AuthorLoginPage(driver) breaking
                    //my constructor chain.
                }
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            BaseClass clz = new BaseClass("one").new OuterClass("two").new InnerClass("three");
            // prints
            // BaseClass: one
            // OuterClass: two
            // InnerClass: three
        }
    }
```

If you don't want to extend InnerClass from BaseClass then move the initialization logic into a init(String driver) method and call it via BaseClass.this.init(driver):

```
public static class BaseClass {
    public BaseClass (String driver)
    {
        init(driver);
    }


    public void init(String driver){
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".init: " + driver);

    }

    public class OuterClass extends BaseClass {
        OuterClass (String driver)
        {
            super(driver);
        }
        //Does something

        public class InnerClass
        {
            InnerClass (String driver)
            {
                BaseClass.this.init(driver);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you !  i ended up with same thing.